# aggregate data and calculate confidence intervals for sub cohort in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset

```
testData <- structure(list(group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
                                 "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
                                 "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
                                 "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
                                 "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", 
                                 "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", 
                                 "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", 
                                 "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2"), 
                       year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                                2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
                                2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
                                2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), category = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat1", 
                                                                      "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat1", 
                                                                      "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", 
                                                                      "cat2", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", 
                                                                      "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", 
                                                                      "cat2", "cat2", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", 
                                                                      "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", 
                                                                      "cat1"), value = c(30.1660205462388, 96.1649663179749, 183.691571800985, 
                                                                                         1.65328912643215, 9.30044741412784, 182.449748512614, 8.47095574122154, 
                                                                                         23.3081277048748, 53.1188233968077, 34.250829201039, 50.5445297997031, 
                                                                                         120.307165280983, 140.223343284331, 122.319359028798, 43.0193263100948, 
                                                                                         134.417238652291, 106.437343685401, 84.0446901587849, 69.7099679759042, 
                                                                                         132.101156129094, 27.8329259333861, 58.4953521410472, 100.379478360197, 
                                                                                         77.2357869871934, 200.464054913284, 47.6252352008202, 109.598360734847, 
                                                                                         18.1730751285375, 67.5769989539879, 26.7504753716622, 16.8630228114074, 
                                                                                         75.2053705357279, 39.7641860921024, 126.658782796637, 64.8507816634371, 
                                                                                         96.3471066298501, 61.4392604693245, 27.6801895514785, 181.599217867455, 
                                                                                         11.1036117561468, 68.1516849014302, 115.899355317842, 167.032368398535, 
                                                                                         116.634854779718, 144.080455202308, 186.627050299051, 72.3807151133032, 
                                                                                         37.6345953992576, 2.09517321452513, 58.3682650864716, 54.3590148062561, 
                                                                                         53.9884625670805)), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                "data.frame"))
```

and I want to aggregate the data on different levels, and calculate the confidence intervals for `value` at the corresponding aggregation levels. For example, I defined two versions of factor which should be used for the aggregation:

```
cohort1 = c("group" ,"category", "year")
cohort2 = c("group" ,"category")
```

and I have written a function to calculate the confidence intervals:

```
calculateCI <- function(value){
  
  avg <- mean(value)
  s <- sqrt(var(value))
  n <- length(value)
  
  error <- qnorm(0.975)*s/sqrt(n)
  
  lower <- avg - error
  upper <- avg + error 
  
  return(list(lowerCI = lower, 
              upperCI = upper))
  
}
```

How can I aggregate the data and calculate the confidence intervals?

I have tried unsing dplyr:

```
testData %>%
  group_by(cohort) %>%
  group_map(~ calculateCI(.x$value))
```

but it doesn't work with the vector `cohort`. How can I pass a vector as the argument for `group_by`

Also I would like to have the results in a form of a data.table, with a column for lower and upper confidence interval:

```
group category year sumValue lowerCi upperCi
 1: Group1     cat1 2015 320.9763     xxx     yyy
 2: Group1     cat2 2015 301.5985     xxx     yyy
 3: Group1     cat1 2016 476.4137     xxx     yyy
 4: Group1     cat2 2016 526.7104     xxx     yyy
 5: Group1     cat1 2017 464.4076     xxx     yyy
 6: Group1     cat2 2017 269.7241     xxx     yyy
 7: Group2     cat2 2016 481.1285     xxx     yyy
 8: Group2     cat3 2016 832.1817     xxx     yyy
 9: Group2     cat3 2017 296.6424     xxx     yyy
10: Group2     cat1 2017 168.8109     xxx     yyy
```

Comment: Your function returns a list, but I'm guessing all you may need to do is group by what you're interested in, does this return the correct data? All you would need to do is group by different things and then unnest the list at the end. 

testData %>% group_by(group,category,year) %>% summarise(CI = calculateCI(value))

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the mean and SD by groups:

```
tapply(testData$value, INDEX = list(testData$group), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE) 
tapply(testData$value, INDEX = list(testData$group), FUN = sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

or by more than one factor:

```
tapply(testData$value, INDEX = list(testData$category, testData$group), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and calculate the CIs

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

testData %>%
group_by(group, category, year) %>%
summarise(across(.cols = value, .fns = c("n" = ~n(), "Mean" = mean, "StDev" = sd), .names = "{.fn}"), .groups = "drop") %>%
mutate("StE" = StDev / sqrt(n)) %>%
mutate("LowerCI95" = Mean - (1.96 * StE),
     "UpperCI95" = Mean + (1.96 * StE))
```